# Cannot overwrite `events` model once compiled

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have defined the Schema as follows,

**Event.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: {
        type: String        
    },
    end_time: {
        type: Date      
    },
    start_time: {
        type: Date      
    },
    name: {
        type: String    
    },
    place: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Location'
    }
});
eventSchema.index({name: 'text'});
var Event = mongoose.model('events', eventSchema);    
module.exports= Event;
```

And using in one method as follows,

```
 let configuration = require('../../commonservices/service');    
    var eventModel = require('./models/Event');
    var dbHelper = require('../../commonservices/dbHelper');
     module.exports = {   
         getEventsByCountry : function(event,context,callback){            
            var searchString =  event.queryStringParameters.searchParam?event.queryStringParameters.searchParam:'';            
             var countryString =  event.queryStringParameters.country?event.queryStringParameters.country:'';             
           dbHelper.query(eventModel, {$text: {$search: searchString},'place.location.country': countryString},function(error,data){
                        callback(data);       
           });
        }            
};
```

For the first time method gets executed, when i call second time the following error occurs,

> {"errorMessage":"Error while loading
>   usersCreate","errorType":"MongooseError","stackTrace":["OverwriteModelError:
>   Cannot overwrite `events` model once compiled.","at Mongoose.model
>   (E:\TV-81\services\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:376:13)"

Comment: I don't see it in your code here, but somewhere you must be calling `mongoose.model('events', eventSchema);` again, somewhere.

Comment: @Paul it gets executed first time when i make the api call

Comment: yes and twice when make second api call. That time schema was initialized and on second time it executes again forcing that error

Comment: @AsifSaeed not based on what he's shown here.  The module, once required, won't run its code a second time.  If I'm misunderstanding you, I apologize.

Comment: @Paul so this error should not happen right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually triggers when Schema file executes more then once.

require all schema files once after mongoose connection then use it like this

```
  mongoose = require('mongoose')
  eventModel = mongoose.model('events')
```

run the code below in your app.js or right after the connection to mongodb. This will load all model once and then you can use each model like mentioned in the about code snippet

```
    loadModels = function () {

        // loop through all files in models directory ignoring hidden files and this file
        fs.readdirSync(config.modelsDirMongo)
            .filter(function (file) {
                return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== 'index.js')
            })
            // import model files and save model names
            .forEach(function (file) {
                winston.info('Loading mongoose model file ' + file);
                require(path.join(config.modelsDirMongo, file));

            });
    };
```

or you can just require that model after mongoose connection with out looping

Comment: how to make it executable only once?

Comment: i dont think i can follow the same in my code structure, am loading necessary modules based on the route. how can i load only once inside my api file rather than on app.js?

Comment: you cant load this each time you hit specific route. Add it on the top of route file and require that route file once. in this case you have to make sure thiss schema file is not required in another route

Comment: you have a gtalk id or something?

Comment: one more think load other modules based on routes but i think these are just schema you should load it in first place after database connection because you might want schema in multiple routes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134883/discussion-between-asif-saeed-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Mongoose will let you setup schemas before the connection, and then handle them correctly when the connection fires.  Further, he's exporting the compiled Model, which means the call to mongoose.model happens only once and then the results are cached in the requires cache, regardless of how many times the Event.js file is required in the future.